# Why output does not show initialized value -1?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
    string first_name = "???"; 
    int age = -1;               
    cin >> first_name >> age; 
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";    
}
```

According to the book *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd edition (Author: Bjarne Stroustrup)*, when I provide the input

`22 Carlos`

the expected output should be:

`22(age -1)`

But when I run it, I get:

`22(age 0)`

What is the cause?

Comment: Take a look at [this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). As stated on that page, since C++11 the value is set to zero and failbit is set. Before C++11, only the failbit was set.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: So basically the answer is "The book BadBoy21 is reading is wildly out of date"?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, that is about right.

Comment: The book is Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2 edition

Comment: @BadBoy21: The cover of that book claims to take C++11 and C++14 into account. Therefore, it seems very strange to me that the book contains such a claim.

Comment: The initialization of `age` to -1 was probably an easy way by the book's author to check that the extraction failed, although checking the failbit was always possible. Now it is not useful at all and should probably be removed.

Comment: @BadBoy21: As far as I know, that book you are reading is generally considered to be good. My guess is that the author just made one mistake.

Comment: I read errata from author's website: "This is not really an errata, but some implementations zero out an int when >> fails. Eventually all will, but until C++11 none did. So, you get 0 or -1 depending on the vintage of your implementation. "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior described in your book is correct until C++11. Until then, only the failbit was set if extraction failed. The value itself was left unmodified.

However, since C++11, the value is now set to zero, in addition to the failbit being set. See [this reference page on std::istream::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for further information.